# Deploy .NET desktop application from web

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

I want to install my .NET application from a website, which means when user accept terms and conditions, the application start to install automatically. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a "Click Once" application deployment feature, I use it all the time. It allows you to add in various other components that could be necessary for your application. ie. need the sql database installed on the user's computer. check off a box and it's included in the click once installer. You can even tell it to have the program check for updates everytime it is launched to see if there is a new version. It can auto generate the webpage and deploy it too. Then your website can have the accept terms and then forward them to the necessary page, or direct download link.

In VS, open the Properties in the solution explorer, select Publish and there's various settings you can setup there...

Comment: Thanks, it looks like exactly like what I need, but I can not see any place for Terms and conditions, I could find install from a web site, but is there any trick for terms of conditions?

Comment: that you would have to add manually.  Put that in the last sentence first paragraph - "Then your website can have the accept terms and then forward them the necessary page, or direct download link"

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop applications will have an installer application that users can download, this be created via a setup project in visual studio, or alternatively I recommend this installer, its free and allows for various setup options, including terms and conditions etc as you would see in standard installers: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

In addition to this, I would recommend submitting your files to the various anti-virus vendors so they can add your download to their whitelists.

Comment: Thanks, I know about normal routine of setup project, I need to know  if I install the files automatically from a website.

Comment: You can use technologies such as click-once, etc, but you will need to investigate this for what would be a "public" application. If you want to control licensing/activation and copy protection etc, commercial products exist that can handle these things, unless click-once can handle that?